# How can I loop over a multi level JSON object and create a new Javascript object from one of it's key and values

Tags: javascript, json, loops, object, ecmascript-6

I have a JSON object that looks like the following

```
{
    "venue": {
        "time1": [
            {
                "Status": "Available"
            },
            {
                "Status": "Unavailable"
            },
            {
                "Status": "Unavailable"
            }
        ],
        "time2": [
            {
                "Status": "Available"
            },
            {
                "Status": "Available"
            },
            {
                "Status": "Unavailable"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to loop over this object and create a new object that has the times as the key and an array of status' as it's values. So the new object would look like the following...

```
{
   "time1": ["Available", "Unavailable", "Unavailable"],
   "time2": ["Available", "Available", "Unavailable"]
}
```

NB: I'm struggling with this, because i can't manage to reach the array. I have tried various maps, reduce etc. but with no joy, and I can't seem to find the right answer on SO because, I'm not sure what to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a `reduce` over object's key-value pairs to get the desired result.
Here is a snippet for your reference. Comments are inline

```js
const obj = {
  venue: {
     time1: [{Status: "Available"},{Status: "Unavailable" },{Status: "Unavailable" }],
     time2: [{Status: "Available" },{Status: "Available" },{Status: "Unavailable" }]
  }
};

const result = Object.entries(obj.venue).reduce((acc, element) => {
  // Destrcuture key, values here
  const [key, status] = element;
  // Run a map to fetch the status and then assign it to the key
  acc[key] = status.map((item) => item.Status);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! The map inside the reduce function is what I was missing! I had tried various combinations of these as well as a for of loop but couldn't seem to get there. Your solution is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript Object `obj.venue` is converted into an array (`Object.entries(obj.venue)`), each of their `timeX` arrays is then processed (get the `Status`-value of each object) and eventually it is converted back into an object again using `Object.fromEntries()`.

All this can be done in a single line of code:

```js
const obj= {venue: {time1: [{Status: "Available"},{Status: "Unavailable"},{Status: "Unavailable"}],
                    time2: [{Status: "Available"},{Status: "Available"},{Status: "Unavailable"}]} };
                    
const res=Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj.venue).map(([k,v])=>[k,v.map(st=>st.Status)]));

console.log(obj); // original object remains unchanged
console.log(res);
```

Comment: This also would have worked, but I prefer @VJR08's answer as it's a little clearer to understand

Answer (score 0):

```
const a = Object.values(your_object)[0];
a['time1'] = a['time1'].flatMap(x=>Object.values(x))
a['time2'] = a['time2'].flatMap(x=>Object.values(x))
console.log(a)
/*
{
  time1: [ 'Available', 'Unavailable', 'Unavailable' ],
  time2: [ 'Available', 'Available', 'Unavailable' ]
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

POJO (Plain old javascript object) cannot be iterated: [Iterable Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols)

The only solution is to read the object entries and then access the internal array. However, note that iterating over object does not guarantee that the order is maintained [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

That said, you can use any of the object iterable methods ["keys", "values", "entries"] to access the inner data.

Using `entries()`

```
Object.entries(jsonObj.venue).map(entry => console.log(entry))
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this code helping you

```
var json= {
    "venue": {
        "time1": [
            {
                "Status": "Available"
            },
            {
                "Status": "Unavailable"
            },
            {
                "Status": "Unavailable"
            }
        ],
        "time2": [
            {
                "Status": "Available"
            },
            {
                "Status": "Available"
            },
            {
                "Status": "Unavailable"
            }
        ]
    }
}
Object.keys(json.venue).map((obj,index)=>json.venue[obj] = json.venue[obj].flatMap(ele=>Object.values(ele)),[])
console.log(json)
```